# Ruby: merge two hash as one and with value connected

Tags: ruby, hash, merge

2 hash:

```
h1 = { "s1" => "2009-7-27", "s2" => "2010-3-6", "s3" => "2009-7-27" }

h2 = { "s1" => "12:29:15", "s2" => "10:00:17", "s3" => "12:25:52" }
```

I want to merge the two hash as one like this:

```
h = { "s1" => "2009-7-27 12:29:15",
      "s2" => "2010-3-6 10:00:17", 
      "s3" => "2009-7-27 2:25:52" }
```

what is the best way to do this? thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
h = h1.merge(h2){|key, first, second| first + " " + second }
```

It will work if your keys are the same. In your code, they aren't ("s1" vs "s1="). Are they supposed to be the same keys?

Comment: Thanks for answering Chubas. But, if `h1` and `h2` don't have the same keys, the logic breaks. Any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You mean:

```
Hash[h1.map{|k,v| [k, "#{v} #{h2[k]}"]}]

 => {"s3"=>"2009-7-27 12:25:52", "s1"=>"2009-7-27 12:29:15", "s2"=>"2010-3-6 10:00:17"}
```

Note hashes are unordered, if you want an ordered hash you probably need to look [at this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/OrderedHash)

Comment: Your "look at this" link is dead, Sam.